# Segepay payment gateway got error

Tags: php, codeigniter, opayo

Sagepay payment gateway integrate in Codeigniter on my local system.

When I am tried sandbox URL and Pay payment it was successfully done but When I am tried live URL that time I got this type of error

> "ERROR - There was an error during the payment process.

The error details are:

> 2003 : An ERROR has occurred on the Sage Pay System

I am using **`5404 0000 0000 0001`** this card detail.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your account has actually been put live - Sage Pay won't put the transaction types onto your account until you have successfully tested the account etc. Best to give them a call to check.

Also - that card number can't be used on the live environment - you'll have to use a real one!